# remove records from csv file and put them into a new file using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a requirement where I have to search incorrect email id's from a particular field (Field Alias from below example) of a csv file and put them into a new file, then delete those records from the original file.

For example, I have this csv file:

```
id,name,corporate_email,alias,location
1,wek,wek@xyz.com,wek@xyz.com, IL
2,rek,rek@qwe.com,rek@qwe.com,IL
3,peter,peterli@xyz.com,peter li,MI
4,Aaron,Aaronli@que.com,Aaron li, MI
```

Here I want to extract records from the Alias column with incorrect email id's like record 3 and 4 and want to put these 2 records in another csv file and remove these 2 records from the original file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awk function, File1.csv is your initial CSV file, replace 'Regex' with a pattern that corresponds to your data in the field alias.

```
awk -F,  '{ if ($4 !~ /^\S{1,}@\S{2,}\.\S{2,}$/) {print >> "matched.csv"} else {print >> "not_macthed.csv"} }'  file1.csv
```